# piping postgres COPY in python with psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, copy, pipe, psycopg2

I'm writing a script to do a copy of some data between two machines on the same network using psycopg2. I'm replacing some old, ugly bash that does the copy with

```
psql -c -h remote.host "COPY table TO STDOUT" | psql -c "COPY table FROM STDIN"
```

This seems like both the simplest and [most efficient](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/07/05/how-to-insert-data-to-database-as-fast-as-possible/) way to do the copy. It's easy to replicate in python with a stringIO or a temp-file, like so:

```
buf = StringIO()

from_curs   = from_conn.cursor()
to_curs     = to_conn.cursor()

from_curs.copy_expert("COPY table TO STDOUT", buf)
buf.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
to_curs.copy_expert("COPY table FROM STDIN", buf)
```

...but that involves saving all the data to disk/in memory.

Has anyone figured out a way to mimic the behavior of a Unix pipe in a copy like this? I can't seem to find a unix-pipe object that doesn't involve POpen - Maybe the best solution is to just use POpen and subprocess, after all.

Comment: Curious is the below solution worked?

Answer (score 16):

You will have to put one of your calls in a separate thread.  I just realized you can use  [os.pipe()](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/os.html#os.pipe), which makes the rest quite straightforward:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
import os
import threading

fromdb = psycopg2.connect("dbname=from_db")
todb = psycopg2.connect("dbname=to_db")

r_fd, w_fd = os.pipe()

def copy_from():
    cur = todb.cursor()
    cur.copy_from(os.fdopen(r_fd), 'table')
    cur.close()
    todb.commit()

to_thread = threading.Thread(target=copy_from)
to_thread.start()

cur = fromdb.cursor()
write_f = os.fdopen(w_fd, 'w')
cur.copy_to(write_f, 'table')
write_f.close()   # or deadlock...

to_thread.join()
```

Comment: This is a great solution! I’m curious though as to why it was necessary to introduce a Thread object?

Comment: @Demitri, `copy_from()` and `copy_to()` are blocking commands; they don't return until the operation is finished.  If we made the first call in the main thread, it would just wait for data on the pipe and we would never get control back to make the other call.

Comment: Ah, I see. It will still block on the new thread, but allow the main thread to feed the pipe at one's leisure. Thanks.

Comment: Could this be used to pipe/stream SQL commands into psycopg2, rather than buffering up all the SQL commands in one go? I have a situation where `raster2pgsql` streams out lots of SQL commands, and this meant to be piped into `psql`, or in my case psycopg2. In this situation, I have a STDOUT stream from a subprocess call, which will be outputting SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a deque that you've subclassed to support reading and writing:

```
from collections import deque
from Exceptions import IndexError

class DequeBuffer(deque):
    def write(self, data):
        self.append(data)
    def read(self):
        try:
            return self.popleft()
        except IndexError:
            return ''

buf = DequeBuffer()
```

If the reader is much faster than the writer, and the table is large, the `deque` will still get big, but it will be smaller than storing the whole thing.

Also, I don't know for sure `return ''` when the `deque` is empty is safe, rather than retrying until it's not empty, but I'd guess it is. Let me know if it works.

Remember to `del buf` when you're sure the copy is done, especially if the script isn't just exiting at that point.